# Property of one class is passed as parameter to constructor of another class. How to resolve this with Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am new with Autofac and this is scenario of my problem:

I have 2 classes, both of them are singletons.

One of them has some public property, eg.

```
public class ClassWithProperty
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and the second class has a constructor which should take a property from first class as parameter:

```
public class ClassWithConstructor
  {
    private string _someParameter;

    public ClassWithConstructor(string someParameter)
    {
      _someParameter = someParameter;
    }
  }
```

without Autofac I can just do it like this:

```
var classWithProperty = new ClassWithProperty();
var classWithConstructor = new ClassWithConstructor(classWithProperty.SomeProperty);
```

I cannot resolve this problem with Autofac and find any solution here or in google.
What I do:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ClassWithProperty>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ClassWithConstructor>()
    .WithParameter() // what should be done here to pass exactly ClassWithProperty.SomeProperty here?
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
var container = builder.Build();
```

of course it is simplified scenario just to show my problem. In real scenario I pass TreeList from one form to another view class and working exactly on that TreeList.

Comment: Start by reading https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components . Note how you can `Resolve` - do that, and read the property there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a lambda to manually construct your `ClassWithConstructor`

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ClassWithProperty>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => new ClassWithConstructor(c.Resolve<ClassWithProperty>().SomeProperty))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

or

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ClassWithProperty>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register<ClassWithConstructor>()
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
              (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) && pi.Name == "someParameter",
              (pi, ctx) => "sectionName"))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```